# How to join video files from pipes and disk using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

How can I concatenate video files from different source in the same command: pipes (mkfifo) and from the file system (no reencoding) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# files.txt
file 'clip1.mov'
file 'clip2.mov'
file 'clip3.mov'
```

```
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mov
```

[Fun with ffmpeg: Joining video clips](https://radavis.github.io/cli/fun-with-ffmpeg/#joining-clips)

Comment: I need to be able to use files from the disk together with the data stored in pipes (fifo)

Comment: Take a look at this example. It might be what you are looking for: https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Concatenating-using-the-concat-protocol-_0028file-level_0029

Comment: `file` can be a named pipe.